# Prove that $T$ and $L\lambda$ satisfy...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

$\mathsf{Lemma\;34.3}$: Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional complex vector space.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical parts of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccesilbe to screen readers. If you do not know how to write math, then please read [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141). Lastly, please read: [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/145141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer. Then 
$$
  TL_\lambda^n
= T\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}T^i (\lambda I)^{n-i}
= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}T^{i+1} (\lambda I)^{n-i}
= \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}T^i (\lambda I)^{n-i}\right)T
= L_\lambda^n 
$$
since all matrices commute with powers of themselves and with the identity. In particular, the equality holds for $n=1$, and so the first two properties you are to show hold.

Now, 
\begin{align}
   L_\lambda L_\mu
&= (T - \lambda I)(T - \mu I) \\
&= T^2 - \mu T - \lambda T + \lambda \mu I \\
&= T^2 - \lambda T -\mu T  + \mu \lambda I \\
&= (T - \mu I)(T - \lambda I) \\
&= L_\mu L_\lambda
\end{align}
establishes the third property.